# How do I tidy up the following Play Framework routing?

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to follow the sample in 'Introducing the Play Framework'.  I have deployed work to date here

http://vivid-beach-8523.herokuapp.com/

When I do a search for example IPad it comes up with the 'messy' URL

http://vivid-beach-8523.herokuapp.com/search?search=ipad&submit=Search

I think I have routing setup correctly (in conf/routes) because when I use the 'clean' URL it comes up with the correct result

http://vivid-beach-8523.herokuapp.com/search/IPad

I'm not sure how to get my form to display the clean URL. The raw HTML is

```
<div id="searchdiv">
    <form action="@{Application.search()}" method="GET">
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Application.search is as follows

```
public static void search(String search, Integer page) {
    if (page == null) page = 1;
    SearchResults results = AuctionItem.search(search, page);
    render(results, page, search);
}
```

Any help on what I need to change much appreciated.  In case it is needed the routes file looks like the following

```
GET     /listing/create           Application.createAuctionItem
POST    /listing/create           Application.doCreateItem
GET     /listing/show/{id}             Application.show
GET     /listing/show             Application.show
GET     /search/{search}     Application.search
GET     /search     Application.search
GET     /                                       Application.index
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a name in your submit buttons. Otherwise it would be sent as an parameter of the form.
Just put

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
```

should be fine, I guess.
And you need to match the URL in the form as the one you specified in routes.
One possible solution with jQuery might look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchdiv form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // not a good design though, once you change the route to Application.search, 
    // this will failed
    this.attr('action', '/search/'+$('input#search').val());
    this.submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, the number of parameters in Application.search() does not match with the form. This could be another problem